# Language, Proof, and Logic 14.11 Fitch Proof

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

Been stuck on this question for awhile now and I just don't know how to get Cube(x) so that I can use ^ intro with Cube(x) and ∀y (Cube(y) →  y = a) and then use ∃ intro to get the conclusion. This is what I have so far.[image]

This is the original question if needed (14.11).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Universal elimination can be to any term in the context, which includes the assumed witness for the existential.

```
|_ Ex Ay (Cube(y)<->y=x)                Premise
|  |_ [a] Ay (Cube(y)<->y=a)            Assumption
|  |  Cube(a)<->a=a                     Universal Elimination
|  |  :
|  |  :
|  |  Ex (Cube(x) & Ay (Cube(y)->y=x))  Existential Introduction
|  Ex (Cube(x) & Ay (Cube(y)->y=x))     Existential Elimination
```